# Do fuses affect a PC PSU's amperage output?

Tags: power-supply, amperage, fuses

I have a PC PSU powering a load that *should* pull 20 Amps. I put a 10 Amp fuse in series with the load and the PSU. However, the fuse simply will not burn, and the PSU continues to supply the load, albeit at a weaker output (the load doesn't operate as quickly as without a fuse).

Is the PC PSU somehow accounting for the fuse and lowering its output? I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: From a practical point of view the answer is no, although you might get a really tiny voltage drop across the fuse. It might be worth describing your setup and the load in more detail, more likely the fuse holder or wire connecting it is introducing excessive resistance.

Comment: Find out what's getting hot--there's your voltage drop.

Comment: The fuse is probably dropping enough voltage to reduce the voltage at the load ... but not QUITE enough to blow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could depend on the fuse characteristics eg fast-acting, slo-blo, hrc, etc.

For example, on fuses protecting direct on-line motor starter circuits, the fuse needs to be able to handle up to 10 x motor rating current during inrush (while motor starts).

Also the fuse should only be used on circuits with a voltage LESS than the fuse rating.

If you put your multimeter in series with the fuse and the load, what current are you reading? 
Assuming it is 20A or above, that would explain why the PSU output is dropping which will be nothing to do with the fuse.

The following may be a useful reference:
http://fuseparametricsearchtool.bussmann.com/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The answer is only very slightly as Ambiorix and PeterJ explains.

The thing to note with fuses is they are thermal devices and take time.

I have put 20A through a Fluke meter for more than a minute before it blew the 10A protection fuse. (I didn't know the fuse was 10A at the time or that the meter wasn't calibrated for it either ..oops )

There are different fuses but what you find is that a 10A fuse has to last (almost) indefinitely at 10A.

The fuse blowing is an exponential behaviour. when you get to 2 times the rated current some fuses last 1 minute or more, at 2.1 time they may last 30 seconds and at 10 times they all react very fast... but it depends on the type of fuse.

Answer (score 0):

- Virtually all PSUs have an integrated current limiter circuit. This circuit typically reacts much faster than a common thermal fuse.
- It does not mean that a load that's rated at 20A draws this current under all circumstances. It could well be that this is only in certain modes or at maximum setting.

The best way to verify the operation of the current limiter is via a variable dummy load. Measure the voltage over and current through the load and observe the readings when you increase load gradually. If you don't have such a device try finding a load that's confirmed to be below the the maximum rating (10A) and check the readings.